# word similar to obfuscation, used for comedy

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, american-english, british-english, humor

there is a word, or perhaps a type of comedy, where simple things are described using terms that are correct but needlessly complicated or absurd for various effects. I am reminded by comics from nathanwpyle on Reddit and twitter examples:
[example one](https://twitter.com/nathanwpyle/status/1097056176599117824)
[example two](https://twitter.com/nathanwpyle/status/1102693504533360640)
other example sources are welcome
Edit: possibly tangentially related to [observational comedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_comedy)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a noun to describe such a way to speak or write, there is

circumlocution

noun

> a roundabout or indirect way of speaking; the use of more words than necessary to express an idea.
>
> a roundabout expression.

(Dictionary.com)

An example:
"The driveway was not unlike that military training device known as an obstacle course” is a circumlocution for “The driveway resembled an obstacle course.

Comment: Either circumlocution is not necessarily funny, or you chose a particularly weak example. I guess *funny* can't be defined, anyhow. Although, Is it intended to rhyme on *electrocution*? A memorable example in my mind is abuse of technical terminology: *dihydrogen monoxide exfiltrated from a civic resident aquifier*, or *tap water* for short.